# How to avoid Picasso download from url when the image was just uploaded by the app and I can associate the URL with a bitmap loaded in memory

Tags: android, picasso

Long title, but the question is simple.

In my app i upload a picture to AWS server and will use it further during the runtime. I would like Picasso to cache it and associate it to the resulting url, avoiding loading it on next executions.

Can it be done? Basically i would need to add an entry to its cache with the 'body' containing the image and the header of the http could be simulated.